# Why is partial $\dfrac{\partial \sin y(t)}{\partial t} = y'(t)\cos t$ when $\dfrac{\partial\sin y(t)}{\partial y} = 0\text{ ?}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Easy question: Why is $\dfrac{\partial \sin y(t)}{\partial t} = y'(t)\cos t$ when $\dfrac{\partial\sin y(t)}{\partial y} = 0\text{ ?}$

See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+derivative+sin(y(t))+wrt+t for more.

Comment: Hint:  Use the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the chain rule, when you take the  derivative of a function within a  function you multiply their derivatives.

Therefore, $\partial_t(\sin(y(t)))  = y'(t)\cdot\cos(y(t))$

The reason why $\partial_y(\sin(y(t))) =0$ is because the given function is independent of the variable $y$.

$y(t)$ should not be confused with $y$, one is function notation while the other is a variable.

If you want to calculate $\partial_{y(t)}\sin(y(t))$ this would give ;

$\partial_{y(t)}\sin(y(t))  = \cos(y(t))$